# mail attachments

Tags: html, servlets

i am implementing mail application with attachments using html and java servlets

Here's the html code

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" size="20" multiple>
```

in the servlets,

```
String attachments[]=  request.getParameterValues("attachment");
```

is returning null what other way can i use to implement this

Comment: nopes that question was after you know the file to be uploaded my question is how to pass file select values to servlet and get them as Strings

Comment: The value of a file element is a file. The control displays a file name to the user so they know what they have selected, not so it can be sent to the server.